# PHP/Laravel Query Efficiency

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am calculating basketball stats and have the models Stat, User (which the basketball players are held within), Team, Stat_Meta, Game, Season, Substitution.

I have a view called statTable that can be added to any other view on the app. statTable basically just iterates through each player on the team and retrieves the calculation for each stat type (found in Stat_Meta model). Within those calculation, there are queries run for the Stat, Game, Season, etc. tables. By the time it iterates through every player and all their stats, we are looking at like 500 queries PER game (often we are going through like ~30 queries/view, so you do the math, it's bad).

My question: With the Laravel debug bar installed, I can see that in my test environment, I've got 3,116 queries running when loading the front page, and 2,432 of them are duplicates. It takes forever to load as well. **So, how can I re-work this system of queries to reduce the number of them?**

Full disclosure, I'm not a CS person, so efficiency isn't something I'm trained in. Right now, I'm super happy this even works, but not it is going to cost me an arm and a leg to do all these queries at scale (not to mention horrible UX).

Comment: Looks like you're doing calculations inside your code. It would be best if you let the database server do the calculations (SUM/AVG per group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some optimization of your queries by using Laravel's ***eager loading***. Definition of eager loading from official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
>   data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not
>   actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent
>   can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model.
>   Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

You can read some great examples from the link I provided. I believe this will optimize your queries a lot.

Beside eager loading, you should always aim to accomplish as much as you can with your queries instead of processing data with PHP, Laravel collections, etc.